How to read data from Felica(Japan) card in Flutter app
im a newbie in flutter development and I'm trying to build a flutter app that can read data from Felica card.
I have done some research on internet and asked chatgpt about this but still have not found a clear solution to this. Has anyone done this feature before, if so please give me some guidance here please, thank you in advance

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

NFC is very hardware specific in terms of the reading hardware and Tag hardware.
I would start of with reading the datasheet for the specific Felica Tag you are trying to read.
Felica Tags can also NFC Type 3(F) standard Tags, you can read the specification they need to conform to to be here
Then you can move on how the reader hardware behaves generically
More specifically how to read Tags using a native API
And the specific NFC technology that the reader hardware platform supports
Once you have done all this you can look for a flutter package that has wrapped all this up for you, or create your own interface to the native code.
There are a few NFC flutter packages that wrap the native code but NFC Type3(F) Tags are less common and I don't know how well the are supported by the flutter packages.

Thanks for your response @Andrew I'll go have a look at this
